How to fix "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'" in Angular
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
I've faced this problem in my Angular app and import **FormsModule ** or ReactiveFormsModule doesn't solved it.
So i've fixed this way:
Go to app.module.ts and insert your component inside @NgModule > declarations.
And of course import both modules i've quote above (FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule).
It's worked for me.
Tha's will solve the problem.
At least, it's worked for me.

So i've fixed this way:
Go to app.module.ts and insert your component inside @NgModule > declarations.
And of course import both modules FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule.
It's worked for me.

If you are using Module based Angular, import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule into your Module file.
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule],
})
export class TestModule {}

If you are using Standalone Components in Angular, import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule into your component.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgIf, NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgIf,
        NgFor,
    ],
})
export class TestComponent {

}

